# Exceptions with java agents (-javaagent:XXXX.jar )

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, javaagents, invocationtargetexception

Anybody can provide me with a suggestion/solution to fix this problem?

Java Version : JDK 1.6 --UPDATED

I am trying to add a jar file into eclipse VM arguments through javaagents:
[image]
But this seems to have an error when i run a simple code

```
package jassmodernexample;
import jass.modern.Pre;
import java.io.*;

public class Bar {
@Pre("args.length % 2 == 0")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, " + args.length);
     }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
>       at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
>
> Caused by: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:** javax/tools/JavaCompilerTool$CompilationTask
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at jass.modern.core.bytecode.contracts.ContractClassFileTransformer.(ContractClassFileTransformer.java:50)
>       at jass.modern.core.bytecode.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:62)
>       ... 6 more
>
> Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**: javax.tools.JavaCompilerTool$CompilationTask
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 20 more
>
> FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Comment: what version of the jdk are you using?